# Convert CSV to JSON with first common column being the object

Tags: php, json, csv

With the given csv information is it possible to pickoff the common category in the first column to be the object for the other items to produce the resulting JSON.

```
  +----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
  |category  | itemName    | price      |description |src       |  
  +----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
  | cars     | toyota      | 10000      | 4 door     | image    |
  +----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
  | cars     | mazda       | 12000      | 2 door     | image    |
  +----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
  | cars     | honda       | 10000      | 5 door     | image    |
  +----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
  | Trucks   | Hino        | 10000      | 2 door     | image    |
  +----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
  | Trucks   | Mack        | 10000      | 2 door     | image    |
  +----------+-------------+------------+------------+----------+

  {
      vehicles: [
          {
              name: "cars",
              items: [
            {
                itemname: "toyota",
                price: "10000",
                description: "4 door",
                src: "image",

            },
            {
                itemname: "mazda",
                price: "12000",
                description: "2 door",
                src: "image",

            },
            {
                itemname: "honda",
                price: "10000",
                description: "5 door",
                src: "image",

            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "trucks",
        items: [
            {
                itemname: "Hino",
                price: "10000",
                description: "2 door",
                src: "image",

            },
            {
                itemname: "Mack",
                price: "10000",
                description: "2 door",
                src: "image",
                  },

              ]
          }
      ]
  };
```

Comment: The problem is really 'how can I group arrays based off an index'?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already ?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn`t test the script , you can fix it if needed :

```
$columns = array();
$vehicles = array();
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  if(0 == count($columns)) {
    foreach($line as $col=>$field) {
      $columns[$col] = $field;
    }
  }
  else {
    $row = array();
    foreach($line as $col=>$val){
      $field = $columns[$col];
      if($field == 'category'){
        $type = $value;
        $vehicles[$value] = array('name'=>$value);
      }
      $vehicles[$type]['items'][$field]  = $value;
    }
  }
}
$result = json_encode($vehicles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way of doing it, using [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode). Since you haven't attempted solving this issue yourself, this could use some cleanup, but other than that, it works.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $csv);
$keys = explode(",", strtolower($lines[0]));
unset($lines[0]); // remove the keys line

$data = array();
// loop
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $item = explode(",", $line);
    $type = $item[0];
    // unset the un-needed stuff
    unset($item[0]);
    unset($keys[0]);
    // add
    $data['vehicles'][$type]['name'] = $type;
    $data['vehicles'][$type]['items'][] = array_combine($keys, $item);
}
```

You can view the outputted JSON [**Here**](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=f377201b3a7c636b20d31ad7f028432d)

[**Working Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#CGlRoqy4r)